Free Variables in Quantified Proposition (from Discrete Math Rosen Textbook)

I'm just confused 2 things:

Based on what I underlined in red, would the statement (also underlined in red) "there exists an x such that x + y = 1" (I'll assume domain of discourse for x and y is the real numbers) actually be a proposition? I would say no because y is not bounded, but I want to make sure.

I'm not fully sure what the thing I underlined in green is saying, and what is "formula" exactly referring to here. Kindly could someone please help clarify.



From the statement underlined in red, a proposition has no free variables.
Thus, your answer to bullet 1. is correct; in formula $\exists x (x+y=1)$ the varibale $y$ is free, while $x$ is bound because it is in the scope of the leading existential quantifier.
What is the scope of a quantifier? It is the part of the formula on which the quantifier applies: usually specified by parentheses, as in the case of $\exists x (x+y=1)$ where the scope of the existential quantifier is the part $(x+y=1)$.
In a formula like $\exists x P(x) \land Q(x)$ the scope of the quantifier is only the part $P(x)$: thus, the variable $x$ in $P(x)$ is bound while the $x$ in $Q(x)$ is free. Comapare with $\exists x (P(x) \land Q(x))$ where there are no free variables.
Note: Rosen calls proposition a formula with no free variables: usually called closed formula (aka: sentence). This correspond to the notion of page 2: "A proposition is a declarative sentence (that is, a sentence that declares a fact) that is either true or false, but not both."
Rosen calls propositional function a formula with free variables: usually called open formula.
A formula is an expression (finite string of symbols) that is correct according to the syntax of the language (see page 350); it is a statement of the mathematical language.
See also the glossary of Key Terms, page 110.
